# Windows 7 illegally shuts down when it goes to sleep

Tags: windows-7, laptop, sleep, shutdown

I have a Thinkpad T420. Recently, made a fresh install of the stock OEM Win 7 on it. Subsequently used Slimdriver to install latest drivers that the bundled Lenovo ThinkVantage missed out on updating. Slimdriver mostly detected newer versions Nvidia drivers, which ThinkVantage missed.

I am not very sure whether it is because of these Slimdriver installs, but now whenever the machine goes to sleep ( either on inactivity or lid close ), it shuts down illegally.

I have fiddled with almost all the power option settings; both on Win 7 power options and Lenovo Power Manager

1. I have the "hybrid sleep" turned OFF.
2. However, if I turn ON "hybrid sleep", the computer doesn't shut down illegally but goes into "hybrid sleep"
3. I do not want hybrid sleep. I just want normal sleep.

Comment: I would rule out the Slimdriver installation as the reason this behavior is happening then edit your question

Answer (score 0):

there are lots of odds with the powermanagement system that comprises the bios, chipset hardware, the operating system, the drivers and probably other stuff no one even knows about.

notebook manufactures fiddle around with this fragile system to get the computer running with exact the bios, operating system and drivers on release date (or before that). Therefor it´s not uncommon that operating system or driver updates incommodate powermanagement features. for example older (updated) notebooks run not as silent as when they where new (even with clean fan). they just don´t reach the lowest powermenagement levels due to driver/bios/os conflicts.

try the powermanagement drivers (chipset, cpu, notebook manufacturer preset) the device originally came with. load the bios defaults. if this combination enables the desired powermanagement features, you can update step by step to find the culprit.